# How to make TabControl with Caliburn.Micro and diffrent UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

i have a problem with TabControl and i dont know how to even start.

I have my root view that i named `MainViewModel`. `Csharp` class looks like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    //i have couple of ToggleButtons to load diffrent UserControls, LoadAddNewPage 
    //is one of them
    public void LoadAddNewPage() => this.ActivateItem(new AddNewTaskViewModel(params));
}
```

I Have `ToggleButton` in `MainWindowView.XAML` that loading `LoadAddNewTaskPage`.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="LoadAddNewPage"               
            Grid.Column="4"
            Width="50" Height="50" 
            Content="&#xf067;" 
            Foreground="White" 
            BorderThickness="0"  
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
            Background="#FF085078" Margin="20,3,0,3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <!-- i deleted data triggers here -->
    </ToggleButton>
```

As you can see above, it loading `AddNewTaskViewModel` with form to add new item to my database/list (or whatever).

That `AddNewTaskView.xaml` is simple `UserControl` with textboxes etc.

My question is, how to prepare my `LoadAddNewPage` button to load `TabControl` with two `UserControler`? For now, i loading `new AddNewTaskViewModel()` (it is `UserControl`, it loads properly as i want to ). How to make `TabControl` with `Caliburn.Micro` that will store `AddNewTaskViewModel` and `AddNewProjectViewModel`? How to make switch in `TabControl` between two diffrent `UserControl`? I have a problem to start, because i dont know how to start with this problem. Thanks for any advices

**EDIT**

Here i will show my full ViewModel

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view) => Show.LoginBox(this.loggedUser);

    public void LoadUserInfoPage() => this.ActivateItem(new UserInfoViewModel(this.loggedUser));

    public void LoadTaskManagerPage() => this.ActivateItem(new TaskManagerViewModel(this.loggedUser, this.repository));

    public void LoadNotificationsPage() => this.ActivateItem(new NotificationsViewModel(this.repository));

    //here, i want to trigger TabControl with two VMs to choose
    public void LoadAddNewTaskPage() => this.ActivateItem(new AddNewTaskViewModel(this.loggedUser, this.repository));
}
```

**EDIT2**

I get the context, but i want to achive:

make another `Vm` class, that will store my `User Controls` that i want to use in my `TabControl`:

```
public class TabControlViewModel 
{
    //how to store two VMs that i will use to my TabControl here?
}
```

And in `MainViewModel`:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    //activate TabControlViewModel that will store AddTaskVM and AddProjectVM
    //this vm will display on my `TabControl` in xaml in `MainWindowView.xaml`
    public void LoadAddNewPage() => this.ActivateItem(new TabControlViewModel(params));
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add another `Button`. Or how do you know when to add a `AddNewTaskViewModel` versus a `AddNewProjectViewModel`?

Comment: Yes, i could add new buton to activate new item, but in my project i want to try to do `TabControl` that will load diffrent `ViewModel`, depends on which button in `TabControl` i will click on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `TabControl` named "Items" to the view:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items" />
```

...and another `Button` and method that adds the other type of `Screen` to the `Items` collection:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel  : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public void LoadAddNewTask() => this.ActivateItemAsync(new AddNewTaskViewModel());
    public void LoadAddNewProject() => this.ActivateItemAsync(new AddNewProjectViewModel());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for investing your time, but could you be more specific please? What about `TabItem`? And where and how store `Items`? How `Caliburn` will know, which `VM` he need to load?

Comment: What about `TabItem`? This is a visual that will be created by the `TabControl` when you call `ActivateItemAsync` to add a new item to it. And the "vm to load" is the one that you pass to the `ActivateItem` method.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, your snippet from `MainWidnowVM` means, that you have two `bindings` (for example to `buttons` that names `LoadAddNewTask` and `LoadAddNewProject`). Maybe i dont understand something, but from where property `Items` come from, and what is that methods doing (from `MainWindowVM`)? If you can, could you provide your answer with more complex explenetion, whats going on there?

Comment: `Items` is a property of the `Conductor<T>` base class. Caliburn.Micro is all about conventions. If you want to know how it works, I suggest you read the [docs](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/).

Comment: Ok, i get it, thanks. But as i mentioned in my question, `LoadAddNewPage()` is not my only button in my `MainWindowVM`. I want to use `TabControl` on specific button only (show tab control on that button click). Can i use `Items` property in (for example) new `ViewModel` (`LoadAddNewPage() => this.ActivateItem(new TabViewModel(params))`), there store VMs that you mentioned and again, `activate` it on choosed tab from `TabViewModel`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. My sample adds two different view models to the same `TabControl`. You may obviously implement your methods as you want.

Comment: i shared my full `VM` class. maybe now it will be clear. I cant simple use `Items` as you mentioned. I want to have `TabControl` only on one button click. In that method, i want to trigger next ViewModel that will store `ViewModels` to add `Project` and `Task` i think now it will be more clear

Comment: Trigger next view model? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: you should put the TabControl in the `TabControl`, you mean, first TB should be `TabControlViewModel`? Sorry for not specified question

Comment: Sorry, if `TabControlViewModel` should "to store two VMs that i will use to my TabControl", you should put the `TabControl` in the `TabControlView`.